# For all non-zero positive integers $a, b, c$ prove $[a, b, c] = \frac{abc (a, b, c)}{(a, b) (b, c) (c, a)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

they could help me, I have applied the definition of mcd and mcm but there is a construction that I do not achieve

Comment: I think the body of your question isn't quite complete

Comment: Your terminology is non-standard...I'm guessing that " mcd, mcm" mean "gcd, lcm" but I am not sure.  Similarly your notation is unclear.  what does $[a,b,c]$ mean, for example?  Perhaps an explicit example would help.  Say $a=2, b=4, c=6$.  How does this play out?

Comment: @lulu I'm not familiar with $[\,]$ notation, but $(\,)$ means gcd for sure. I suppose $[\,]$ means lcm though

Comment: I think you need to explain what the notations $[a,b,c]$ and $(a,b,c)$ and $(a,b,c)$ mean.  I'm guessing that the square brackets mean least common multiple, and the parentheses mean greatest common divisor, but even if I'm right, this needs to be stated explicitly.

Comment: @Jakobian  Sure, and I figure $[,]$ refers to lcm, but the OP should confirm.

Comment: Hint:  assuming we've got your notation right, it suffices to work prime by prime.  Let $p$ be a prime dividing $abc$ and show that the powers of $p$ match on both sides.

Comment: sorry the notation refers to gcd (a, b, c) and lcm [a, b, c]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $p$ be any prime and without loss of generality order $a,b,c$ so that $\nu_p(a)\geq \nu_p(b)\geq \nu_p(c)$ ($\nu_p(n)$ is the number of times $p$ divides $n$ for any positive integer $n$ and prime $p$). Can you show that the number of times $p$ divides the left side is the same as the number of times $p$ divides the right side?